# BottomSheetBehaviour enable Drag to top

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

I have implemented a layout with the `BottomSheetBehaviour`and set have set the `behavior_peekHeight` as 300dp and `behavior_hideable` as `true`.

**Code Sample**

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/map_view_height"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="300dp"
    app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/sheet_content_layout"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here I'm able to hide the layout with dragging to the bottom. But once I have dragged the layout to the bottom, I couldn't drag it back to it's original peek height. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think it is good to ask the user to drag it from the bottom, especially for those who are using software bottom.

Comment: @BakaWaii I'll be showing a minimal section to be dragged to the top. For example, if you use the new Uber you will be able to drag the messages from the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `BottomSheet` with multiple `peekHeight`. That means you can't set the height of `BottomSheet` in expanded state. At least, not without modifying the `BottomSheetBehavior` class to your specific use case. This may help in that regard: [Sliding up image with Official Support Library 23.x.+ bottomSheet like google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335366/sliding-up-image-with-official-support-library-23-x-bottomsheet-like-google-ma/37474350#37474350)

However, if you just want a bottomSheetView that is at a height of say 100dp in collapsed state and that can be expanded to full screen and dragged back to 100dp, you can use the default behavior.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/sheet_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/map_view_height"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/sheet_content_layout"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

You could also have a look at physics based animation introduced this year in IO. It has an easy to use FlingAnimation class, https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/preview/fling-animation.html