# Bottom Sheet Above Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet, bottomnavigationview

My goal is to place a "bottom sheet" on top of a `BottomNavigationView` like this:

[image]

But it stays the following way. Both views collapse:

[image]

This is the xml of my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tierrota"
tools:context="com.example.juanjose.myapplication.ViajesActivity">

<!-- include main content -->
<include layout="@layout/bottomsheet" />

<!-- include bottom sheet -->
<include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code of `bottom_navigation`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorClarito"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And code of bottom sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundSemi"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Bandeja de entrada"
    android:fontFamily="@font/eraslght"
    android:textColor="@color/colorLetra"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="coisa2"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am new with these two elements. Is there someone who knows any way to achieve what I'm looking for?

I want my "bottom sheet" to act as such and can expand. My ultimate goal is to add a `RecyclerView` inside the `BottomSheet`.

Comment: Do you want the bottom sheet to work like bottom sheet? From your example it looks like a simple `ImageView` and `TextView` will do the job for you if you don't want to animated show/hide the bottom sheet.

Comment: I want it to act as such, I have edited my question, thank you

Comment: Please see my answer. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the two elements inside a linear layout. Not sure how coordinator layout behaves but I think it will not allow you to "order" elements (similar to frame layout).

Answer (score 7):

To use the **BottomSheet**, it should be a child of the **CoordinatorLayout**. Here I have used relative layout as a parent layout for bottom navigation to stay at the bottom and then CoordinatorLayout above bottom navigation.
Here's a [article](https://iamnaran.medium.com/bottom-sheet-above-bottom-navigation-b10a0c92edd) that will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/view_bottom_sheet_top" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/near_by"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/normal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Book Now"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimaryText"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_maps"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/bottom_view"
                android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </RelativeLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="1dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorContainerBackground"

            />
<!--              Start BottomNavigationView -->

       
<!--              End BottomNavigationView -->


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't forget to add this in your Activity/Fragment

```
private RelativeLayout bottomSheetParentLayout;
    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehaviour;

   mBottomSheetBehaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetParentLayout);

  if (bottomNavigation != null) {

        mBottomSheetBehaviour.setPeekHeight(bottomNavigation.getHeight() + 90);

    }
```

[image: Output will look like this]

Comment: The approach assumes that we do not have things like CollapsingToolbarLayout/Toolbar.  How are those to be handled?

Comment: That's will be a different question to answer @RowlandMtetezi for more here's a link https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474350/6560792

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood your question, you want the `RecyclerView` to be shown in your bottom sheet. That is what makes the problem a lot easier. Let me tell you how.

You need to have a fixed height for your bottom navigation like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorClarito"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your bottom sheet, configure the `RecyclerView` with a `clipToPadding` attribute in it. Which will have some padding at the bottom of your `RecyclerView`. The idea is to have nothing in the covered area of the `RecyclerView` which is coming out with the bottom sheet.

Here's how you should declare your `RecyclerView` in your bottom sheet.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="80dp" />
```

Note that, I set the `paddingBottom` exactly to `80dp` which is the height of the navigation view.

I hope this might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you also have a CollapsingToolBar/Toolbar arrangement, this is the best solution for you:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cord_main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/home_bottom_navigation_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/home_frag_toolbar"
                style="@style/Widget.Toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:logo="@drawable/ic_infinet_logo_white"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back_arrow" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/home_frag_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/mini_player_height"
            app:behavior_skipCollapsed="false"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/player_frag_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/player_mini_frag_container"
                android:name="com.kokonetworks.kokonet.player.PlayMusicMiniFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/mini_player_height" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_bottom_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_background"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_background"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/home_bottom_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It ensures that:

- BottomSheet is a child of the CoordinatorLayout
- BottomNavigation is still rested at the bottom
- CollapsingToolbar/AppBarLayout arrangement is still in place as expected

Answer (score 0):

To use the BottomSheet, it should be a child of the **CoordinatorLayout**, as iamnaran said. 
So simply:

1. Put everything in RelativeLayout
2. Put BottomSheet in CoordinatorLayout
3. Set the BottomNavigation property "alignParentBottom" to true
4. Make new xml file in /res/value and put

   ```
    <resources>
      <dimen name="bottomNavigationHeight">50dp</dimen>
    </resources>
   ```
5. Set the MarginBottom of the CoordinatorLayout (parent of BottomSheet) to

   ```
   android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottomNavigationHeight"
   ```

You can skip steps 4 and 5 by setting the MarginBottom of the CoordinatorLayout to:

```
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
```

But this may lead to confusion in near future

The whole code should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/clBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottomNavigationHeight">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/standardBottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="9dp"
            style="?attr/bottomSheetStyle"
            app:layout_behavior = "com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp">

        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bttm_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu_nav"
        >
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Im using 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

```
val Int.dp: Int
    get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()

class SomeDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        // Translate the bottom sheet so that it appears above the Tab Bar
        val contentView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null)
        dialog.setContentView(contentView)
        (contentView.parent as View).translationY = (-56.dp).toFloat()

        ...
```