# Bottom Sheet in fragment behind BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, bottom-sheet, android-bottomnavigationview

In my fragment, on a button click I need to show a bottom sheet dialog but it must appear from behind the bottom navigation bar. A similar problem has already been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649649/bottom-sheet-above-bottom-navigation) but 
due to some strains, I need to create the bottom sheet by extending BottomSheetDialogFragment only.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">   

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigationHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />    

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom_nav_rounded"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_bottom_navigation_text"   
        app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_bottom_navigation_text"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/navigationHost"
        app:menu="@menu/dashboard_navigation_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FragmentHome.kt**

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {
    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentHomeBinding::bind)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.openBottomSheet.setOnClickListener {
            val bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog()
            bottomSheetDialog.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "TEST")
            bottomSheetDialog.enterTransition
        }
    }
}
```

**BottomSheetDialog.kt**

```
  public class BottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet_login, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjEsa.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong fragment manager, but not sure if that will fix your issue. Change to: `bottomSheetDialog.show(childSupportFragmentManager, "TEST")` and remove the `bottomSheetDialog.enterTransition` to see if that helps

Comment: @Indiana did the changes but no success.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of how its appearing?

Comment: @Indiana I have updated the screenshots.

Comment: ahh, I see what you mean. I misunderstood. This is the correct expected behavior for a BottomSheet. You may have to look at a custom view or another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with `BottomSheet` or `Snackbar`, you need to add a `CoordinatorLayout` as a `parent` root view on the `activity`. Put a `CoordinatorLayout` as a parent, and inside that put your `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: It doesn't work